# Maximo Anywhere 7.6 - Lookup selection not displayed in the field

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I have created a lookup and able to see the data. But when an entry is selected in the lookup, the selection is not displayed in the previous screen. Below are code snippets.

View:

```
<groupitem id="ServiceRequest.CreateSR_serviceRequest_groupitem_ServiceRequest.CommodityGroup_0" >
                        <text editable="true" id="ServiceRequest.CreateSR_serviceRequest_groupitem_ServiceRequest.CommodityGroup_0_CommodityGroup" label="Service Group" lookup="ServiceRequest.CommodityGroupLookup" lookupAttribute="commodity1" placeHolder="Tap to enter" resourceAttribute="commoditygroup">
                        </text>
                    </groupitem>
```

Lookup:

```
<lookup id="ServiceRequest.CommodityGroupLookup" label="Select Value" resource="commodityGroup">
            <requiredResources id="ServiceRequest.commodityGroupLookup_requiredResources">
                <requiredResource id="ServiceRequest.commodityGroupLookup_commodityGroup" name="commodityGroup"/>
            </requiredResources>
            <list id="ServiceRequest.CommodityGroupLookup_commodityGroup_list" resource="commodityGroup">
                <listItemTemplate id="ServiceRequest.CommodityGroupLookup_commodityGroup_listItemTemplate">
                    <listtext cssClass="bold textappearance-medium" id="ServiceRequest.CommodityGroupLookup_commodityGroup_desc" resourceAttribute="commodity"/>
                </listItemTemplate>
            </list>
            <returnAttributes id="ServiceRequest.CommodityGroupLookup_returnAttributes">
                <returnAttribute id="ServiceRequest.CommodityGroupLookup_servicegroup_description" sourceAttribute="description" targetAttribute="description1"/>
                <returnAttribute id="ServiceRequest.CommodityGroupLookup_servicegroup_category" sourceAttribute="commodity" targetAttribute="commodity1"/>
            </returnAttributes>
        </lookup>
```

Resource:

```
<resource describedBy="http://jazz.net/ns/ism/asset/smarter_physical_infrastructure#Z_ODS_ServiceGroups" additionalData="true" id="commoditygroup" name="commodityGroup" pageSize="50" providedBy="/oslc/sp/SmarterPhysicalInfrastructure">
            <attributes id="commodityGroup_attributes">
                <attribute describedByProperty="spi:commoditiesid" id="commodityGroup_commoditiesid_oslccommotieisid" index="true" name="commoditiesid"/>
                <attribute describedByProperty="spi:commodity" id="commodityGroup_commodity_oslccommodity" index="true" name="commodity"/> 
                <attribute describedByProperty="spi:description" id="commodityGroup_description_oslcdescription" index="true" name="description"/>
                <attribute describedByProperty="spi:parent" id="commodityGroup_parent_oslcparent" index="true" name="parent"/>
                <attribute describedByProperty="spi:servicetype" id="commodityGroup_serviceType_oslcservicetype" index="true" name="serviceType"/>
            </attributes>
            <queryBases id="commodityGroup_queryBases">
                <queryBase id="commodityGroup_queryBase_getServiceGroups" name="getServiceGroups" queryUri="/oslc/os/z_ods_commoditygroup"/>
            </queryBases>
            <whereClause id="commodityGroup_whereClause"/><!--  clause="spi:servicetype=PROVIDE"/> -->
        </resource>
```

Under SR Resource:

```
<attribute describedByProperty="spi_wm:commoditygroup" id="serviceRequest_spi__wmcommoditygroup" index="true" name="commoditygroup"/>
```

Could you please help me in this? I have been struggling on this for quite sometime now.

Regards,
Karthik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The targetAttribute of the lookup needs to point to the field in the Service Request resource that you want to store the result in.  It looks like you should have this.

```
<returnAttributes id="ServiceRequest.CommodityGroupLookup_returnAttributes">
            <returnAttribute id="ServiceRequest.CommodityGroupLookup_servicegroup_category" sourceAttribute="commodity" **targetAttribute="commoditygroup"**/>
        </returnAttributes>
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. It worked. is there a documentation available explaining the use of app.xml tags and it's attributes?

Comment: unfortunately not yet.